# Using auto layout to orientate stack views vertically in portrait and horizontally in landscape

Tags: swift

What is the best way to get a vertical stackview in portrait to align horizontally in landscape. I have tried code and auto layout solutions and they have not worked. Is there any simple way to do this in storyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to programmatically update the **`axis`** property of [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStackView/axis) when rotation happens. Docs say:

> The exact layout varies depending on the stack view’s axis,
>   distribution, alignment, spacing, and other properties.

There is no way to achieve this purely using a storyboard.

#### Working solution

I created a demo project and verified it works. I consists of a single view controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator:UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (context) -> Void in

            let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation

            if orientation.isPortrait {
                self.stackView.axis = .Horizontal
            } else {
                self.stackView.axis = .Vertical
            }

            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

`stackView` is a `UIStackView` created in a storyboard with initial axis set to Horizontal.

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer with fully working solution. I verified that this works.

Comment: Thanks. Note the Swift 3.0 version in a separate answer. Also note that to ensure that stackView is correctly orientated when first shown I found I had to move the core of this function (from 'let orientation...' to '...=.vertical}') into a private function that I also call from viewWillAppear. Additional tip: make your contained views have equal withs AND equal heights constraints with each other so that they resize correctly in both display orientations.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) -> Void in

        let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation

        if orientation.isPortrait {
            self.stackView.axis = .horizontal
        } else {
            self.stackView.axis = .vertical
        }

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up switching your if statement to "if orientation.isLandscape" because for some reason it seemed to be working backwards... I've noticed that Xcode doesn't register the rotation correctly when you rotate it so that the home button is on top -- seems like a bug in the Simulator. I'm using Xcode 10.1 with Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

the trick is to set the StackView axis to be Horizontal when the Height is Compact.

Check this post: [Magical View Rotation with StackView](https://www.natashatherobot.com/magical-view-rotation-with-stackview/)

I tried and it worked wonderfully in iOS 13, swift 5

Comment: This will not work on larger devices, as they are never compact in any orientation.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done from your `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.stackView.axis = self.view.bounds.width > self.view.bounds.height ? .horizontal : .vertical
  }

  override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    self.stackView.axis = self.view.bounds.width > self.view.bounds.height ? .horizontal : .vertical
  }
  
  override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.stackView.axis = self.view.bounds.width > self.view.bounds.height ? .horizontal : .vertical
  }
}
```

Note: `statusBarOrientation` from the accepted answer is now a deprecated API... also that's an indirect approach to checking orientation that will fail in some situations. Just check the width and height of the view — it's fully under your control and reliable.

Comment: I wanted to use this but unfortunately this doesn't work reliably enough. viewWillTransition checks the current bounds but sets the future axes, so the ternary setting is backwards in that method. Also transitioning from landscape left to landscape right, and vice versa, is allowed but throws the viewDidTransition ternary off. didRotate has been deprecated and no longer works on current deployments.