# iOS: how to have a different layout depending on app orientation?

Tags: ios, uikit, orientation, uistackview

I use `UIKit` and would like to have a completely different interface depending on the app orientation. I actually have 4 buttons on a view, here is how I want to display them:

[image]

I know that I can play around with trait variations, setting two different constraints and installing one for regular height and the other for compact height, but I don't know how to do such a different layout in that case.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you designing your layout in Storyboard / Interface Builder ... or via code?

Comment: @DonMag I am using Interface Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - step-by-step...

Add 4 buttons to your view controller:

[image]

Embed Buttons 1 & 2 in a stack view, and embed Buttons 3 & 4 in a stack view:

[image]

Give each stack view these settings:

[image]

Now, embed the two stack views in another "outer" stack view:

[image]

Same stack view settings:

[image]

and constrain this "outer" stack view Leading / Trailing / Bottom at 40-pts.

Next, select the Buttons 1 & 2 stack view, and in the Attributes Inspector pane click the `+` to the left of `Axis` and change `Width` to `Any` and `Height` to `Compact`:

[image]

Click **Add Variation** and it will look like this:

[image]

Change the `hC: Vertical` to `hC: Horizontal`:

[image]

Do the same thing with the 3 & 4 stack view.

Now when you rotate the device, it will look like this:

[image]

Adjust the constraints and your stack view `Spacing` from 40 to your desired values.

No code needed - everything is handled by auto-layout!

Comment: That's clever, I didn't think of embedding two vertical stack views in a super stack view like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to group buttons 1+2 & 3+4 into StackView. Setup for StackView different axises for different orientations.

Check out [Using auto layout to orientate stack views vertically in portrait and horizontally in landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676308/using-auto-layout-to-orientate-stack-views-vertically-in-portrait-and-horizontal/43103270)